# Can't retrieve claims added after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I need to temporarily add certain claims to the user, the value of which can change and hence I need to add those claims only when a user successfully logs in. But when I search for this claim in `HttpContext.User`, it's not there. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is my login controller.

EDIT: Using ASP.NET Core 1.0, and ASP.NET Identity. Not using Identity Server.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginIdentityModel lim)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(lim.username);
    if (user != null)
    {
        Claim c = new Claim("ProductUploadRequest", "Allow");
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, c);
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, lim.password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
             var usr = HttpContext.User;//claim not found here
        }
}
```

Comment: Need more info. Are you using identityServer4 ? Can you provide the authorization flow ?

Comment: not using identity server

Comment: Ok to all trying to work out the same problem. use policies and claims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/659) discussion, `HttpContext.User` isn't updated by a `SignIn` call and it is by design:

> Normally the ClaimsPrincipal is only modified with the result of sign in for the next request when it returns with the Cookie.

As a workaround to retrieve the claims immediately, try:

```
_userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 2):

`await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);` should update the claims of the `HttpContext.User` on a subsequent request.

Comment: let me give this a try